# Mapping Lemma for Spectral Sequences in Weibel's book - Help with the proof

Tags: proof-verification, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

We start by recalling the definition of a morphism in the category of Spectral Sequences:

> a morphism $f \colon A \to E$ is a family of maps $f^r_{pq}\colon A^r_{pq}\to E^r_{pq}$ in the abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, with $d^rf^r=f^rd^r$ such that each $f^{r+1}_{pq}$ is the map induced by $f^r_{pq}$ on homology.

Now the Mapping Lemma [Weibel page 123, 5.2.4] tells us

> Let $A,E$ be spectral sequences in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$. Let $f \colon A \to E$ be a morphism of spectral sequences such that for some fixed $r$, $$f^r\colon A^r_{pq}\to E^r_{pq}$$ is an isomorphism for all $p$ and all $q$. **Then the 5-Lemma implies that**  $$f^s\colon A^s_{pq}\to E^s_{pq}$$ **is an isomorphism for all** $s\geq r$ **as well**

The part I don't understand is the highlighted part.

Why we need 5-lemma? In fact, according to me, if $f^{r+1}_{pq}$ is the map induced in homology, then by hypothesis we have that $f^r_{pq}$ is an isomorphism, therefore it induces in homology an isomorphism and so by induction we are done. Where are (if any) the mistakes in this reasoning?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I also have doubts about it.

Comment: @Fyhswdsxjj it's been ages so take everything with a pinch of salt, but I believe I was right. Actually you can use 5-lemma to prove that an isomorphism of say abelian groups induces an iso in homology (modulo it factors through homology, but thats' the definition of a maps of sseq) (Pretty sure the same reasoning goes verbatim in the contex of abelian cats - but again it's been ages I'm not thinking about these things)